# Issue creating a carousel with html CSS and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a carousel using just HTML, CSS and JS.

It works, but not as well as I was hoping for.

When it finishes one round of images, it takes roughly 8 seconds to start showing the images from the first to the last one, and then it stops again for several seconds and so on...

Additionally, the div containing the background-images is 100% width and 100vh height. I've tried to set the background properties like `bg-repeat`, `bg-size`, `bg-position`, but I can't manage to get the images to display well on the screen - They images become cropped when set `background-size: cover`, and become too small if I set `background-size: contain;` or another property.

Can you please check this "working" demo? Thanks.

```js
var divi = document.querySelector(".divi");
srcArr = ["https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300"];
var iter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  if (iter == (srcArr.length)) {
    iter = 0;
  } else {
    divi.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + srcArr[iter] + "')";
    iter++;
  }
}, 4000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.divi {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="divi"></div>
```

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be clear, are you asking to why the slider takes time to transition?

Comment: Every four seconds, you run this `if` statement: `if (iter == (srcArr.length))`. Only if it is **false** do  you change the image: `divi.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + srcArr[iter] + "')";`. This means that, if that statement is **true**, the image will not change for another  4 seconds.

Comment: you have to put all your images in mémory, and switch them by changing class where each one has is own background image, or use URL.createObjectURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Tyler Roper**  says, when (iter == srcArr.length)  iter go on zero value but didn't change the image, so for the next one they wait 4 seconds more.

```js
const
  divi   = document.querySelector(".divi"),
  srcArr = ["https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300"];
var iter = -1;

setInterval(function() {
  iter = (iter + 1) % srcArr.length;
  divi.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + srcArr[iter] + "')";
}, 4000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.divi {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="divi"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every four seconds, you run an `if` statement, and only if it evaluates to `false` do you change the image. That means that each time it evaluates to `true` (when it gets to the end of the array), it has to run  through *two* iterations to continue (which in this case takes 8 seconds).

Personally, I prefer to put things like this in functions, and using a recurring `setTimeout` over a `setInterval`. I've also returned that timeout in the event you want to stop the slideshow at some point.

In regards to your background, that's a pretty broad question. For starters, I've just applied `background-position: center;`.

```js
const divi = document.querySelector(".divi");
const srcArr = ["https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300","https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300","https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300", "https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/300"];
const timer = 1000;

const nextImg = (imageArray, index) => {
  divi.style.backgroundImage = `url('${imageArray[index]}')`;
  index = ++index % imageArray.length;
  return setTimeout(()=>nextImg(imageArray, index), timer);
};

const startSlideshow = imageArray => nextImg(imageArray,0); 

//Start slideshow
const slideshow = startSlideshow(srcArr);

//Stop slideshow
//clearTimeout(slideshow);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.divi {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="divi"></div>
```